# Printing lists without brackets on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if someone could help so when the user enters in 'English,' 'Spanish,' or 'Both' It prints out the list without the brackets and speech marks, I only want commas. I tried looking around but nothing worked for my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
english_list = ["fire","apple","morning","river"]
spanish_list = ["fuego","manzana","manana","rio"]
english_to_spanish = dict(zip(english_list, spanish_list))
spanish_to_english = dict(zip(spanish_list, english_list))


def viewwordlist():
    if word == 'show':
        wordlist = input("""
    Type 'English' to view the English word list
    Type 'Spanish' to view the Spanish word list
    Type 'Both' to view both of the word lists
    """).lower().strip()
        if wordlist == 'english':
            print("Here is the current English word list:")
            print(english_list)
        elif wordlist == 'spanish':
            print("Here is the current Spanish word list:")
            print(spanish_list)
        elif wordlist == 'both':
            print("Here is both the current English and Spanish word list:")
            print("Current English list:")
            print(english_list)
            print("Current Spanish list:")
            print(spanish_list)
        else:
            print("Sorry, that wasn't a option. If you need some assistance please enter 'help'")
```

Comment: Instead of describing the output you want, show us the exact desired sample output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
english_list = ["fire","apple","morning","river"]
```

If you just `print` a `list` Python will include the apostrophes and square braces, because that is the syntax it uses.

```
>>> print english_list
['fire', 'apple', 'morning', 'river']
```

If you just want the words delimited by a comma, you can use a quick `join` expression

```
>>> print ', '.join(english_list)
fire, apple, morning, river
```

Comment: Oh... duh. Thanks! Cut me some slack, I just got back from work :)

Comment: Consider the slack to have been cut :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I am getting a syntax error when I put that code in. Would you know why that is? Thanks

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Swap that out to `print(', '.join(english_list))`

Answer (score 2):

use `join`

```
>>> english_list = ["fire","apple","morning","river"]
>>> print ",".join(english_list)
fire,apple,morning,river
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join:

```
print ', '.join(english_list)
```